# Does Microsoft Outlook treat multiple recipients in an email rule as "and" or "or"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

Suppose I create an email rule and in the "To" field, I enter "alice@aol.com" and "bob@aol.com". Will this rule apply to

1. any email addressed to either Alice or Bob (and maybe others),
2. any email addressed to both Alice and Bob (and maybe others), or
3. any email addressed to exactly Alice and Bob and no others?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Base on [this question](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/creating-rules-for-multiple-recipients.814196/) (which might be too old), I would say that the answer is "and".

Comment: @Community Could you clarify what about my question is unclear? I don't see what's ambiguous about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the below condition?

If so, when I type to address and click, "Or" is displayed between the two addresses. And based on my test, I found that this rule is triggered whenever the recipient address contains one of the addresses.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: I'm on Outlook for Mac, which doesn't show the "or"s between recipients, but it appears that Outlook for Mac uses the same logic and implicitly connects the recipients with "or"s (although there's no way to see that using the Outlook for Mac interface).